# Ruby fields initialization

Tags: ruby, attributes, initialization

In this tiny class when the `@sides=10` statement is executed?
How this statement is related to the `initialize` method?

```
class Poligon
    attr_accessor :sides
    @sides=10
end
```

I am mostly used to Java where it is common to have inline initialization for the attributes. I am now trying to understand the complete initialization procedure for Ruby but I was not able to find it.

Comment: Found information about the subject in this blogpost: http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answers:

- The statemen `@sides = 0` (which actually [is an expression](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html)) is exectuted when the `class` expression in evaluated.
- It is not related at all with the `initialize` method.

As you write it, the `@sides` variable is a *class instance variable*, i.e. an *instance variable* of the `Poligon` object (remember that in Ruby classes are objects of class `Class`). You must initialize *instance variables* inside a method definitions (perhaps inside the `initialize` method). Consider this example:

```
class Poligon
  @class_sides = 'class instance variable'
  def initialize
    @instance_sides = 'instance variable'
  end
end

Poligon.instance_variables
# => [:@class_sides]

Poligon.instance_variable_get(:@class_sides)
# => "class instance variable" 

Poligon.new.instance_variables
# => [:@instance_sides] 

Poligon.new.instance_variable_get(:@instance_sides)
# => "instance variable"
```

For more information about *class instance variable* and how they relate to *class variables* you can read [this article by Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ClassInstanceVariable.html).

Answer (score 3):

You need to put this `@sides=10` inside a method,with your current class definition.

```
class Poligon
    attr_accessor :sides
    def line
     @sides=10
    end
end

p = Poligon.new
p.line
puts p.sides
# >> 10
```

Comment: That's right. Otherwise you set instance variable of `Poligon` object.

Answer (score 3):

The initialize method is the constructor for the class. If you want, you can initialize your instance variables in the contructor:

```
class Poligon
    attr_accessor :sides

    def initialize(num_sides)
      @sides = num_sides
    end
end
```

But since `@sides` is declared as an `attr_accessor`, you can set/get it directly:

```
p = Poligon.new
p.sides = 10
```